# Making a div's background repeatedly change color with a recursive function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make the background color of a div change repeatedly. (i.e. Make it flash between two colors ad infinitum.) I have used setTimeout to make the function call itself again after it runs, but it appears to only run once and then just stops. I have tried using if clauses as well as switches, but to no avail. What am I missing? Thank you for any advice you can give.

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById("animatebox");

function doAnimate() {

    switch (true) {
        case myDiv.style.backgroundColor = "red":
             myDiv.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
             break;
        case myDiv.style.backgroundColor = "blue":
             myDiv.style.backgroundColor = "red";
             break;
    };

    setTimeout(doAnimate, 20);

};

doAnimate();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code does run every 20ms, but you don't use `switch` correctly. Also, if you read the `backgroundColor` property, it may return some other representation of the color such as 'rgb(255,0,0)' for red. Try this:

```js
var myDiv = document.getElementById("animatebox");
var i = 0;    

function doAnimate() {
    if (i++ % 2)
        myDiv.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    else
        myDiv.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  
    setTimeout(doAnimate, 20);
};
    
doAnimate();
```

```css
#animatebox { width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: red; }
```

```html
<div id="animatebox">Flicker!</div>
```